# A probabilistic data structure based on flipping bits with probability $\frac{1}{2^x}$ for counting

Tags: algorithms, data-structures, probability-theory, randomized-algorithms, probabilistic-algorithms

How does this data structure work and what is its application?

```python
class X:
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = 0

    def plus_one(self):
        self.x = self.x + flip(self.x)

    def get(self):
        return 2**self.x #2 raised to the power of x
```

The `flip()` function is a random function that returns $1$ with probability $\frac{1}{2^x}$ and $0$ otherwise.

I suspect that this data structure is somehow related to R. Morris's probabilistic counting algorithm.

The question also mentions that this inequality might be helpful:
$$\log(\mathbb{E}[X])\geq \mathbb{E}[\log(X)]$$

where $\mathbb{E}$ denotes the expected value.

I would greatly appreciate any assistance or guidance.

Comment: I suggest that you [edit] your post to provide full context.  Where did you encounter this?  Can you credit the original source?  You mention "The question" - what question is that?